# Wordpress PHP - Recent Post show images on homepage

Tags: image, show

Here's the PHP at the top of my page

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./blog/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
?>
```

and then I have this at the place where I am wanting to display the most recent post on my website home

```
      <div id="content"><?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
        <div class="post"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content() ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I want to be able to see the images that are posted along with the text, how can I have any additional content from the blog post be displayed on my homepage?

Comment: Why `query_posts` and then `get_posts` later?  And doing it this way brings a lot of overhead into your site - loading a BUNCH of WP files just to load a recent post.  Why not tap into your site's RSS feed?

Comment: I'll try it out and see if it works well for me

Comment: Ok so I've googled RSS feeds and it doesn't seem to work like I want it to. I've got my own table to display content in and I just want to display text, images and possibly information like the data and author. These RSS feeds just seem to be a widget like a box. Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction or paste some code?

Comment: my suggestion is that you actually write the PHP to display the rss feed, not to grab a widget.  You might try checking something like this out: http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/ - it's a small library that you can include and use in your php code to grab the rss feed from your WP site and display the post that way.